# What did Lex Luger say to Sting to pull him off of Ric Flair in early WCW days?

Tags: wrestling, wcw

I remembered watching Monday Night Nitro over Raw for many years. There was a segment where Sting had the scorpion death lock on Ric Flair long after the match was over. Luger came out, said something to Sting, they got up and left. Was it ever known by the public what was "said"?

This was pre-NWO days. Luger was already in the WCW, so around 1994-1996 (Thunder in Paradise was still the show prior to Nitro). There was even a hotline you can call in to get tips about things that happened that weren't broadcast. I called this hotline (something like 3.00 per minute), and hung up after 1 minute because the recording literally would string you along for several minutes talking about upcoming details.

Comment: This is probably going to need made a lot more specific to a particular show episode

Comment: Given the nature of these shows it was probably "Segment's over-running. Knock it off and let's get back to the dressing room". It's unlikely to have been anything "plot" related or specifically meaningful.

Comment: I remembered they advertised what Luger said as one of the items for the hotline. At the least it was a carrot on a stick for the viewer

Comment: Considering things like this happened *a lot* in wrestling entertainment, without proper broadcast date, or better, a video clip would be helpful. But I doubt that even it'd help since this segment has probably followed a scripted storyline which actually doesn't require meaningful thing to say to Sting, Luger just have to trigger the moment and Sting will act on necessary steps to follow up on the script.